# Function that returns the union(in alphabetic order) of two sets in Lisp

Tags: recursion, common-lisp, ordered-set

The procedure below takes two lists and returns their union as an ordered list.

```
(defun stable-union (lst1 lst2)
  (cond ((null lst1) lst2)
        ((null lst2) lst1)
        ((and (null lst1) (null lst2)) nil)
        (t
         (let ((el1 (car lst1))
               (el2 (car lst2)))
           (cond ((string= el1 el2)
                  (cons el1
                     (stable-union (cdr lst1)  (cdr lst2))))
                  ((string< el1 el2)
                   (cons el1
                         (stable-union (cdr lst1)  lst2)))
                  (t
                   (cons el2
                         (stable-union lst1 (cdr lst2)))))))))
```

It works for some examples and fails for others. For example:

```
STABLE-UNION: (STABLE-UNION '(A B C) '(B A D)) failed: 
Expected (A B C D) but saw (A B A C D)
STABLE-UNION: (STABLE-UNION '(A B C) '(A D B E)) failed: 
Expected (A B C D E) but saw (A B C D B E)
STABLE-UNION: (STABLE-UNION '(C B A) '(A E B D)) failed: 
Expected (C B A E D) but saw (A C B A E B D)
```

Can you guide me as to where I am making mistakes in my code? Thank you so much.

Comment: if you write list processing code it is good style to use FIRST and REST, instead of CAR and CDR. You can also write LIST1 instead of LST1.

Comment: Hi Renzo. Thank you for your help. Why are FIRST and REST preferred? Second I found the solution to this problem by going through several trial & errors iterations. Could you tell me why cdring down list1 only instead both list1 and list2 when consing el1 works? Thank you. I am new to Lisp and your explanation will help me a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above function works only for lists that are composed by symbols already  lexicographically ordered. So, for instance, it works correctly for `'(A B C) '(A B D)`, but not for `'(A B C) '(B A D)`.

There are several ways of correcting it. The simplest one is to call it by sorting (with stable-sort) the two arguments, for instance:

```
(defun stable-union-general (lst1 lst2)
   (stable-union (stable-sort lst1 #'string<) (stable-sort lst2 #'string<)))

(stable-union-general '(A B C) '(B A D))
(A B C D)
```

Another, less efficient, way is to change the algorithm by taking into account unordered lists.

Finally note that the third branch of the outer conditional is never statisfied: `((and (null lst1) (null lst2)) nil)`

This is because, in this case, the first branch is true and the function returns `nil`.